# Toast is not showing in firebase query?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

Toast is not showing in firebase query?
if users found it shows users list but when users not found it does not show toast.I want to show Toast when users not found.My Code is:

```
query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            Iterable < DataSnapshot > children = dataSnapshot.getChildren();

            for (DataSnapshot child: children) {
                User value = child.getValue(User.class);
                if (value.getCity().equals(city) && value.isDonor()) {
                    data.add(value);
                    keyList.add(child.getKey());
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(AdminSearchview.this, "Donors not Found!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Here is Json snippet.Now it will be more clear to test.Now You can see whole json file i have posted.Hope so find better solution.

```
{
  "users" : {
"1aduZZLM15e7BfVLMb66ZUw9lS82" : {
  "blood_Group" : "A+",
  "city" : "Faisalabad",
  "donor" : true,
  "email" : "asghar@yahoo.com",
  "gender" : "Male",
  "mobile" : "03652325554",
  "name" : "Asghar",
  "password" : "asghar",
  "uid" : "1aduZZLM15e7BfVLMb66ZUw9lS82"
},
"5aqisXp6MGVczHQpot3YmcTcLjW2" : {
  "blood_Group" : "B+",
  "city" : "Faisalabad",
  "donor" : true,
  "email" : "irfan@yahoo.com",
  "gender" : "Male",
  "mobile" : "03066521016",
  "name" : "Irfan",
  "password" : "fani12",
  "uid" : "5aqisXp6MGVczHQpot3YmcTcLjW2"
},
"K3ERR6YBIFSqrEP1SBL8fvh39J22" : {
  "blood_Group" : "O+",
  "city" : "Faisalabad",
  "donor" : true,
  "email" : "abdullah@yahoo.com",
  "gender" : "Male",
  "mobile" : "03067908636",
  "name" : "Abdullah",
  "password" : "abdullah",
  "uid" : "K3ERR6YBIFSqrEP1SBL8fvh39J22"
},
"NfnrLN3B68Ty0oOCpAxOSqNhVL53" : {
  "blood_Group" : "AB+",
  "city" : "Faisalabad",
  "donor" : true,
  "email" : "bilal@yahoo.com",
  "gender" : "Male",
  "mobile" : "03167846423",
  "name" : "Bilal",
  "password" : "bilal12",
  "uid" : "NfnrLN3B68Ty0oOCpAxOSqNhVL53"
},
"Q8LWIShbfcdIeixwGQbtFh99UgT2" : {
  "blood_Group" : "AB-",
  "city" : "Faisalabad",
  "donor" : true,
  "email" : "arslan@yahoo.com",
  "gender" : "Male",
  "mobile" : "03227637423",
  "name" : "Arslan",
  "password" : "arslan",
  "uid" : "Q8LWIShbfcdIeixwGQbtFh99UgT2"
},
"RqYsc92qBYhMbMexa7jMrrMEqU83" : {
  "blood_Group" : "A-",
  "city" : "Faisalabad",
  "donor" : true,
  "email" : "arshad@yahoo.com",
  "gender" : "Male",
  "mobile" : "03214569842",
  "name" : "Arshad",
  "password" : "arshad",
  "uid" : "RqYsc92qBYhMbMexa7jMrrMEqU83"
},
"Sg6KYzywzXRi7s8M6lcyfQUCHSf2" : {
  "blood_Group" : "B-",
  "city" : "Faisalabad",
  "donor" : true,
  "email" : "asif@yahoo.com",
  "gender" : "Male",
  "mobile" : "03007508236",
  "name" : "Asif",
  "password" : "asif12",
  "uid" : "Sg6KYzywzXRi7s8M6lcyfQUCHSf2"
},
"TRqlMF1aAkgJCL8VBEIJbGEJD1j2" : {
  "admin" : true,
  "blood_Group" : "B+",
  "city" : "Faisalabad",
  "donor" : false,
  "email" : "admin@admin.com",
  "gender" : "Male",
  "mobile" : "03046091706",
  "name" : "Admin",
  "password" : "admin1",
  "uid" : "TRqlMF1aAkgJCL8VBEIJbGEJD1j2"
},
"XitGtEPpvfgq2Atx54nBEdagfMs1" : {
  "blood_Group" : "B+",
  "city" : "Faisalabad",
  "donor" : true,
  "email" : "salman@email.com",
  "gender" : "Male",
  "mobile" : "03215467945",
  "name" : "Salman",
  "password" : "salman",
  "uid" : "XitGtEPpvfgq2Atx54nBEdagfMs1"
},
"tg2X3LrtfRN0TT8bM369qj7O5Nf1" : {
  "blood_Group" : "O-",
  "city" : "Faisalabad",
  "donor" : true,
  "email" : "rizwan@yahoo.com",
  "gender" : "Male",
  "mobile" : "03128968656",
  "name" : "Rizwan",
  "password" : "rizwan",
  "uid" : "tg2X3LrtfRN0TT8bM369qj7O5Nf1"
}
}}
```

Comment: Can you post a snippet of your JSON file? That way it will be easier to determine

Comment: http://imgur.com/gE8zkrE

Comment: http://imgur.com/4lag3lC

Comment: If your `onDataChange` doesn't get called, the first thing to do is handle `onCancelled` to ensure you're not ignoring an error message there. `public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }`.

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: Ok, i will add.

Comment: The problem is that, this else part does not run at all.

Comment: JSON snippet added. @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: check this...  @YunusKulyyev

Comment: What is your `onCancelled` method returning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i have solved by adding this line instead of else statement.

```
                if (data.size() == 0){
                    Toast.makeText(AdminSearchview.this, "Donors not Found!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that `dataSnapshot.exists()` is always true. Try to check `dataSnapshot.getChildren().size()` instead of `dataSnapshot.exists()` and if the size is 0 show the Toast

Comment: If his child node is empty, .exists() returns false

Comment: There is no size method in getChildren()

Comment: You can use `dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()`

Answer (score 0):

### you can use this method to Show Toast

```
 query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                Iterable < DataSnapshot > children = dataSnapshot.getChildren();

                for (DataSnapshot child: children) {
                    User value = child.getValue(User.class);
                    if (value.getCity().equals(city) && value.isDonor()) {
                        data.add(value);
                        keyList.add(child.getKey());
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }else {
                Toast.makeText(AdminSearchview.this, "Donors not Found!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
                }
            } 
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you explain what is different from the question's code? Or what the OP did wrong in his code.

Comment: I have already tried this. This method shows toast when find users.else remains same no response.